# Saving WS payload into database in Camel

Tags: jpa, jax-ws, cxf, apache-camel

I'm absolutely newbie in Apache Camel. I'd like to create a very simple app in which it would accept WS calls and save the payload into a database using JPA. 
The payload's structure is quite simple. The root is a Marriage object. It contain some String and int and Date fields, a wife, a husband and a list of children (Person objects).

My goal is to save these data into two tables of a database: MARRIAGE, PERSON.

I've successfully created a jaxws:endpoint in which I listen and respond a dummy response.
I've created the tables and JPA entities.

I don't know how to "connect" the WS implementation with the spring configured JpaTemplate. Should I solve this problem with Camel routing using somehow a @Converter class or @Injet it into the WS implementing class by Spring. I'm confused.

Should I use cxf endpoint instead of jaxws endpoint?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `camle-cxf` endpoint if you want to use camel. What I would do is expose the endpoint as a `camle-cxf` endpoint. Something like this:

```
<camel-cxf:cxfEndpoint id="listenerEndpoint"
                       address="http://0.0.0.0:8022/Dummy/services/Dummy"
                       wsdlURL="wsdl/DummyService.wsdl"
                       xmlns:tns="http://dummy.com/ws/Dummy"
                       serviceName="tns:Dummy"
                       endpointName="tns:DummyService">
    <camel-cxf:properties>
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true"/>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD"/>
    </camel-cxf:properties>
</camel-cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Then I would have a simple Spring bean like this:

```
<bean id="processor" class="com.dummy.DummyProcessor">
     <property name="..." value="..."/> //there goes your data source of jdbc template or whatever...
</bean>
```

If you want to use `JPA` just configure all the configuration and inject your entity manager into this bean.

The actual class would look something like this:

```
public class DummyProcessor {

    @Trancational //If you need transaction to be at this level...
    public void processRequest(Exchange exchange) {
        YourPayloadObject object = exchange.getIn().getBody(YourPayloadObject.class);
        //object - is your object from SOAP request, now you can get all the data and store it in the database.
    }
}
```

The camel route would be like this:

```
<camel:camelContext trace="true" id="camelContext" >

    <camel:route id="listenerEndpointRoute">
        <camel:from uri="cxf:bean:listenerEndpoint?dataFormat=POJO&amp;synchronous=true" />
        <camel:log message="Got message. The expected operation is :: ${headers.operationName}"/>
        <camel:choice>
            <camel:when>
                <camel:simple>${headers.operationName} == 'YourPayloadObject'</camel:simple>
                <camel:bean ref="processor" method="processRequest"/>
            </camel:when>
        </camel:choice>
        <camel:log message="Got message before sending to target: ${headers.operationName}"/>
        <camel:to uri="cxf:bean:someTargetEndpointOrSomethingElse"/>
        <camel:log message="Got message received from target ${headers.operationName}"/>
    </camel:route>

</camel:camelContext>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Paulius! 

Thanks for your help! Using your sample code I could do what I wanted. Now I can go ahead. My next goal is to integrate my pilot app with jBPM.

Oh, and I accepted your suggestion to replace JAXWS with CXF.